# Using the output of the PyTorch Transformer Tutorial

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, transformer-model

I want to use the output of the PyTorch transformer tutorial ([tutorial page](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/transformer_tutorial.html), [default colab](https://colab.research.google.com/github/pytorch/tutorials/blob/gh-pages/_downloads/9cf2d4ead514e661e20d2070c9bf7324/transformer_tutorial.ipynb)) to do sentence completions.  However, when I try that it just produces nonsense

```
itos = vocab.get_itos()

def generate_text(model, start_sentence, max_len=50, temperature=1.0):
    """
    Generate text using the trained model.
    
    Parameters:
    - model: The trained model
    - start_sentence: The sentence to start the generation
    - max_len: Maximum length of the generated sequence
    - temperature: Determines the randomness of predictions. 
                   Higher values make predictions more random, lower values make it more deterministic.
    
    Returns:
    - generated_text: Generated text
    """
    model.eval()  # Set model to evaluation mode
    with torch.no_grad():
        # Tokenize the starting sentence
        input_tensor = torch.tensor(vocab(tokenizer(start_sentence))).unsqueeze(1).to(device)
        generated_words = [w for w in start_sentence.split()]
        
        # Generation loop
        for _ in range(max_len):
            output = model(input_tensor)
            word_weights = output[-1].squeeze().div(temperature).exp().cpu()
            word_idx = torch.multinomial(word_weights, 1)[0]
            word_tensor = torch.Tensor([[word_idx]]).long().to(device)
            input_tensor = torch.cat([input_tensor, word_tensor], 0)

            # Add generated word to the list
            word = itos[word_idx]
            generated_words.append(word)
            
            # End generation if end-of-sentence token is produced (if it exists in your vocab)
            if word == '<eos>':
                break

        generated_text = ' '.join(generated_words)
        
    return generated_text

# Test the function
start_sentence = "The robot "
generated_sequence = generate_text(model, start_sentence, max_len=100, temperature=2)
print(generated_sequence)
```

results in

```
The robot emulate emulate emulate emulate gaeltacht...
```

If I try lower temperatures it just gives 'The robot robot robot robot`

Unlike the tutorial I trained for 10 epochs.  The final epoch gives

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| epoch   8 |   200/ 2928 batches | lr 2.99 | ms/batch 14.36 | loss  1.20 | ppl     3.33
| epoch   8 |   400/ 2928 batches | lr 2.99 | ms/batch 14.26 | loss  1.23 | ppl     3.44
| epoch   8 |   600/ 2928 batches | lr 2.99 | ms/batch 14.44 | loss  1.16 | ppl     3.20
| epoch   8 |   800/ 2928 batches | lr 2.99 | ms/batch 14.59 | loss  1.18 | ppl     3.25
| epoch   8 |  1000/ 2928 batches | lr 2.99 | ms/batch 14.32 | loss  1.15 | ppl     3.17
| epoch   8 |  1200/ 2928 batches | lr 2.99 | ms/batch 14.29 | loss  1.18 | ppl     3.25
| epoch   8 |  1400/ 2928 batches | lr 2.99 | ms/batch 14.32 | loss  1.17 | ppl     3.24
| epoch   8 |  1600/ 2928 batches | lr 2.99 | ms/batch 14.63 | loss  1.18 | ppl     3.24
| epoch   8 |  1800/ 2928 batches | lr 2.99 | ms/batch 14.31 | loss  1.13 | ppl     3.10
| epoch   8 |  2000/ 2928 batches | lr 2.99 | ms/batch 14.27 | loss  1.18 | ppl     3.27
| epoch   8 |  2200/ 2928 batches | lr 2.99 | ms/batch 14.27 | loss  1.21 | ppl     3.36
| epoch   8 |  2400/ 2928 batches | lr 2.99 | ms/batch 14.64 | loss  1.25 | ppl     3.49
| epoch   8 |  2600/ 2928 batches | lr 2.99 | ms/batch 14.26 | loss  1.24 | ppl     3.45
| epoch   8 |  2800/ 2928 batches | lr 2.99 | ms/batch 14.29 | loss  1.19 | ppl     3.30
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| end of epoch   8 | time: 43.81s | valid loss  0.63 | valid ppl     1.87
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| epoch   9 |   200/ 2928 batches | lr 2.84 | ms/batch 14.67 | loss  1.09 | ppl     2.97
| epoch   9 |   400/ 2928 batches | lr 2.84 | ms/batch 14.33 | loss  1.09 | ppl     2.97
| epoch   9 |   600/ 2928 batches | lr 2.84 | ms/batch 14.39 | loss  1.04 | ppl     2.84
| epoch   9 |   800/ 2928 batches | lr 2.84 | ms/batch 14.30 | loss  1.13 | ppl     3.10
| epoch   9 |  1000/ 2928 batches | lr 2.84 | ms/batch 14.53 | loss  1.06 | ppl     2.88
| epoch   9 |  1200/ 2928 batches | lr 2.84 | ms/batch 14.30 | loss  1.11 | ppl     3.02
| epoch   9 |  1400/ 2928 batches | lr 2.84 | ms/batch 14.30 | loss  1.09 | ppl     2.97
| epoch   9 |  1600/ 2928 batches | lr 2.84 | ms/batch 14.27 | loss  1.09 | ppl     2.96
| epoch   9 |  1800/ 2928 batches | lr 2.84 | ms/batch 14.49 | loss  1.12 | ppl     3.06
| epoch   9 |  2000/ 2928 batches | lr 2.84 | ms/batch 14.56 | loss  1.11 | ppl     3.02
| epoch   9 |  2200/ 2928 batches | lr 2.84 | ms/batch 14.27 | loss  1.07 | ppl     2.92
| epoch   9 |  2400/ 2928 batches | lr 2.84 | ms/batch 14.29 | loss  1.11 | ppl     3.05
| epoch   9 |  2600/ 2928 batches | lr 2.84 | ms/batch 14.39 | loss  1.09 | ppl     2.99
| epoch   9 |  2800/ 2928 batches | lr 2.84 | ms/batch 14.53 | loss  1.08 | ppl     2.95
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| end of epoch   9 | time: 43.87s | valid loss  0.40 | valid ppl     1.49
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| epoch  10 |   200/ 2928 batches | lr 2.70 | ms/batch 14.30 | loss  1.02 | ppl     2.78
| epoch  10 |   400/ 2928 batches | lr 2.70 | ms/batch 14.43 | loss  1.06 | ppl     2.89
| epoch  10 |   600/ 2928 batches | lr 2.70 | ms/batch 14.47 | loss  1.03 | ppl     2.79
| epoch  10 |   800/ 2928 batches | lr 2.70 | ms/batch 14.27 | loss  1.00 | ppl     2.72
| epoch  10 |  1000/ 2928 batches | lr 2.70 | ms/batch 14.36 | loss  1.00 | ppl     2.73
| epoch  10 |  1200/ 2928 batches | lr 2.70 | ms/batch 14.35 | loss  1.01 | ppl     2.75
| epoch  10 |  1400/ 2928 batches | lr 2.70 | ms/batch 14.65 | loss  1.03 | ppl     2.80
| epoch  10 |  1600/ 2928 batches | lr 2.70 | ms/batch 14.29 | loss  1.02 | ppl     2.77
| epoch  10 |  1800/ 2928 batches | lr 2.70 | ms/batch 14.30 | loss  1.01 | ppl     2.73
| epoch  10 |  2000/ 2928 batches | lr 2.70 | ms/batch 14.28 | loss  1.02 | ppl     2.77
| epoch  10 |  2200/ 2928 batches | lr 2.70 | ms/batch 14.55 | loss  0.99 | ppl     2.68
| epoch  10 |  2400/ 2928 batches | lr 2.70 | ms/batch 14.26 | loss  1.06 | ppl     2.87
| epoch  10 |  2600/ 2928 batches | lr 2.70 | ms/batch 14.28 | loss  1.03 | ppl     2.80
| epoch  10 |  2800/ 2928 batches | lr 2.70 | ms/batch 14.26 | loss  1.01 | ppl     2.74
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| end of epoch  10 | time: 44.03s | valid loss  0.66 | valid ppl     1.94
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

One interesting thing is the validation preplexity is lower than the test training perplexity